# Laravel Form Request Not Validating the Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I am using Laravel FormRequest to avoid messy validation request inside my controller. For that, I'm referring this article
https://medium.com/@kamerk22/the-smart-way-to-handle-request-validation-in-laravel-5e8886279271

The problem is every time I called the store method, it throws the following error

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
message: "The given data was invalid."
errors: {affinity_id: ["The affinity id field is required."],…}
affinity_id: ["The affinity id field is required."]
partner_name: ["The partner name field is required."]
tier_id: ["The tier id field is required."]
country_id: ["The country id field is required."]
partner_user_name: ["The partner user name field is required."]
partner_user_email: ["The partner user email field is required."]
partner_user_mobile: ["The partner user mobile field is required."]
contacted_for_id: ["The contacted for id field is required."]
issue_type_id: ["The issue type id field is required."]
comm_mode_id: ["The comm mode id field is required."]
opened_by_id: ["The opened by id field is required."]
assigned_to_id: ["The assigned to id field is required."]
team_id: ["The team id field is required."]
priority_id: ["The priority id field is required."]
tat_id: ["The tat id field is required."]
resolve_date: ["The resolve date field is required."]
status_id: ["The status id field is required."]
description: ["The description field is required."]
```

I'm calling the store method using ajax

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\tracker;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Requests\TicketStoreRequest;

public function store(TicketStoreRequest $request)
    {

        $validators = $request->validated();

        if ($validators->fails()) {
            $data['result'] = false;
            $data['messages'] = $validators->errors()->first();

            return json_encode($data);
        }

    }
```

**Form Request Class**

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'affinity_id' => 'required',
            'partner_name' => 'required',
            'tier_id' => 'required',
            'country_id' => 'required',
            'partner_user_name' => 'required',
            'partner_user_email' => 'required',
            'partner_user_mobile' => 'required',
            'contacted_for_id' => 'required',
            'issue_type_id' => 'required',
            'comm_mode_id' => 'required',
            'opened_by_id' => 'required',
            'assigned_to_id' => 'required',
            'team_id' => 'required',
            'priority_id' => 'required',
            'open_date' => 'required',
            'tat_id' => 'required',
            'resolve_date' => 'required',
            'status_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

This behaviour only occurs when rules are not met. If all the fields are successfully validated then `TicketStoreRequest` class does not throw error.

Comment: You may want to `return response($request);` to see what you're getting in your `store(...)` method.

Comment: Is your store method inside a class, right? Can you post your routes and the output of `dd($request->all())` before the validation line in the controller?

Comment: Not sure what version of Laravel you are using, but the form request will handle everything.  You don't need to test `validated()` and return on failure, it all happens auto-magically (including returning AJAX if it was an AJAX request).  [Why not just read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)?

Comment: I am using x-debugger and my debugger does not stop inside `store` method. I think the error is being returned from the `rules` method of form request.
I am using Laravel 6.9

Comment: Remove `if ($validators->fails()) {...}`,  the incoming request is already valid when arrives to the controller... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Can you check in the console what are you sending with the request?